# How to restrict a fields to admin using rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have 2 level of admins :

- super_admin that should be able to create admins
- admin that should not be able to create admins or super_admins.

They are both boolean in my User model and theses two fields are showing and are editable in the rails_admin dashboard.

The goal is to make the field "admin" and "super_admin" read only for the user that is logged as an admin.

To do so I have put that in my rails_admin.rb file:

```
config.model User do
    unless current_user.super_admin?
      configure :admin do
        read_only true
      end
    end
  end
```

Problem, that doesn't change anything, the field admin is still editable by the simple admin.

I have already tried with `field :admin do` instead of `configure :admin do` .

When I comment the ligne `unless current_user.super_admin?` nothing happen either.

I am assuming I have a syntax error or something in my code but maybe it's something else.
Thanks.

Comment: Please visit this to understand rails admin gem
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rails_admin/0.8.1

Comment: Maybe I missed something but to me I have followed the documentation and still something is not working. If you have a more precise idea of the chapter I may have missed let me know.